# Swift - Why CFString and NSString are assignable?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to understand the magic. Why are some types assignable? Is that because of any declarations in the code, or are those relations hidden from us?

I've made a simple function that is compilable:

```swift
func convert(_ x: CFString) -> NSString { x }
```

However, when I'm trying to do the same with the `String` type, it doesn't work. Only the following code is compilable:

```swift
func convert(_ x: CFString) -> String { x as String }
```

The declaration of the class is empty:

```swift
public class CFString {
}
public class CFMutableString : CFString {
}
```

So how it understands that these types could be assigned to each other? How do I find the whole list of such types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFString and NSString are *toll free bridged* within Objective C.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html

String is Swift. It is bridged to NSString but not to CFString. But you can cast.

Comment: Note that the link in this answer is probably a complete list of Foundation types toll-free-bridged to Core Foundation types, but there are other toll-free-bridged pairs in other frameworks. For example, `CTFont` is TFB to `UIFont` (on iOS) and `NSFont` (on macOS). I don't know of a complete list across all of the SDK.